# How to compare two columns in the CASE statement

Tags: sql, select

I have two columns Speed_A and Speed_B.
Now I will compare both columns and will select the higher one in a new table.
Something like this:

```
SELECT ...

  CASE
        WHEN a.Speed_A > a.Speed_B THEN a.Speed_A
        WHEN a.Speed_A < a.Speed_B THEN a.Speed_B
        ELSE 0 --unknown
    END as SpeedLimit,
```

How does it work?

Comment: If you write it like this you will get 0 when speeds are equal, is this what you want? And what is your problem with this?

Comment: What exactly is the question, it looks like you are doing it right?..

Comment: As the result I get only "0" in the column SpeedLimit. There must be a mistake...

Comment: What is the column's data type? Are there `NULL`s?

Comment: column´s data type is integer. And yes there are nulls

Comment: @Moehre See my updated answer. If performance is not so important you can shorten this with `ISNULL(a.Speed_A,0)` (same with B) to skip handling the `NULL`s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your speeds are numerically typed you might get this as easy as:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN a.Speed_A>a.Speed_B THEN a.Speed_A ELSE a.Speed_B END AS SpeedLimit 
[...FROM SomeWhere...]
```

Your `ELSE` will only occur, when A and B are equal, In this case it doesn't matter, which one you return.

### UPDATE

> column´s data type is integer. And yes there are nulls

If `A is null` return B, If `b is null` return A (works for `A and B is null` implicitly). Otherwise both are not null and therefore the statement above should be perfect

```
SELECT CASE WHEN a.Speed_A IS NULL THEN a.Speed_B 
            ELSE CASE WHEN a.Speed_B IS NULL THEN a.Speed_A
                      ELSE CASE WHEN a.Speed_A>a.Speed_B THEN a.Speed_A ELSE a.Speed_B 
                           END
                 END
       END AS SpeedLimit 
 FROM Dummy
[...FROM SomeWhere...]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a inline max function that return the max between two values something like:

```
create function dbo.InlineMax(@val1 int, @val2 int)
returns int
as
begin
  if @val1 > @val2
    return @val1
  return isnull(@val2,@val1)
end
```

and you can use it like this:

```
SELECT dbo.InlineMax(a.Speed_A, a.Speed_B) 
FROM ....
```

Comment: In most cases UDFs are very bad performer. Depending on indexes and statistics the optimizer is much better with `CASE` then with such a function...

Answer (score 0):

Nested Case and Case without Column Name

```
select 
        CASE ColumnName
        WHEN 'enter value on which you want to execute Than Block'
        THEN
            CASE ColumnName
            WHEN 1 THEN 'return value or Column Name'  
            ELSE   'return value or Column Name in case of else' 
            END
        WHEN 'another condition, value of column on which you want to execute then block'
        THEN  
            CASE WHEN 'Condition etc => ColumnName > 5 or ColumnName ='abc' ' THEN 'return value or column name' ELSE 'return value or column name' END
        ELSE 'return value or column name'
        END as status
    FROM TableName
```